# Ignoring the 'x86' target in ndk-build

Tags: android, build, android-ndk

I have a large project that builds to all available target architectures (arm, arm7, x86).

This project includes some other modules, some of which cannot be built for x86 (it fails to compile when built for x86).

Can i "ignore" this architecture for the given modules somehow? (so they will not be built for this arch?)

Or what is the best way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a set of Android.mk files, you can check the current architecture with $(TARGET_ARCH) variable. You can use

```
ifneq ($(TARGET_ARCH),x86)
  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
endif
```

... and so on

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle different support for architectures is to create different APK for each type.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html